# How to install Micro Focus Data Protector Client 10.91 on SLES 15 SP2?

Tags: installation, systemd, sles, data-protector

Micro Focus Data Protector 10.91 should work with Linux distributions like SLES using systemd, but it seems client instalation does not work:
When I try to install the client, I get an error message ("**[110:101] Client import failed!**") while the installation steps before (Core Component, Core Technology Stack, Disk Agent) looked successful.

When examining the system, I see there is a `omni.socket` service running, but the referenced `omni.service` does not exist (there is no corresponding unit file).
On closer inspection I found a `omni@.service` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, but that seems invalid.

What can I do to fix this?

Here is how the service files look like:

```systemd
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/omni.socket
[Unit]
Description=DATA-PROTECTOR-INET
PartOf=omni.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=5555
Accept=yes
MaxConnections=1000000
MaxConnectionsPerSource=100000

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

# /usr/lib/systemd/system/omni@.service
[Unit]
Description=DATA-PROTECTOR-INET
Requires=omni.socket

[Service]
StandardInput=socket
PIDFile=/var/run/omni.pid
ExecStart=/opt/omni/lbin/inet -log /var/opt/omni/log/inet.log
Type=simple
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

To me those service files seem highly incomplete:
They are missing dependencies like network and local filesystems.

To clarify:
I'm not looking for installation instructions like those the product provides already (they don't work).
Instead I'm looking for a way to make the buggy version work while the vendor is fixing their bugs.

Comment: Note: There is no `sles15` tag yet, and I don't have a score high enough to create one.

Comment: What did the software vendor say when you contacted them?

Comment: They are "working on it"; IMHO they seem a bit clueless, or I didn't reach the required level yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a firewall problem:
Port `5555/tcp` (traditional Data Protector port) was blocked on the client.

As the installation is done using SSH (which was not blocked), downloading and installing of the software worked, but communication with the cell manager (CM) was not possible.

I used these CLI commands to configure the firewall (firewalld); you might want to adjust the port and the zone:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service=omni
# firewall-cmd --permanent --service=omni --set-short="Data Protector"
# firewall-cmd --permanent --service=omni --set-description="Data Protector"
# firewall-cmd --permanent --service=omni --add-port 5555/tcp
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-service=omni
# systemctl reload firewalld.service
```

Note that `firewall-cmd` allows to modify one item only (when trying to change multiple items, the rest is silently ignored (enhancement request exists already)).

Once it worked, it seems the `inet` process returns with somewhat random value what `systemctl status omni*` does not seem to like very much (it reports different errors).

I don't know whether those systemd unit files are in a good condition though (some additional tuning might silence those spurious errors).

I also found out that the installation still uses `/etc/xinetd.d/omni` if xinetd is installed (and running). However xinetd is not reloaded automatically, so it has to be done manually after installation to activate the `omni` service.

Finally Data Protector still installs some files with evil mode `0666`; something one may want to fix (`chmod go-w` at least).